# Cannot add item to memory cache after item expiration

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I'm using Memory cache to prevent re-processing of messages I receive from a queue.

Here is how I create the cache and add items:

```
        _cache = new MemoryCache("TransactionProcessorCache");

        _policy = new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            UpdateCallback = null,
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1)
        };

        _cache.Add("unique key", "value", _policy);
```

I add the first item to the cache and I can retrieve this item for 1 minute which is expected.

But, once the first item expires and the cache becomes empty, the consequent items I add to the cache cannot be retrieved. The cache always behaves as if it was empty despite getting a return value "true" from the _cache.Add(...) call.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.1. The app is a console application. The MemoryCache here is from System.Runtime.Caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line again

```
AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1)
```

You disable cache after 1 min from current time **forever**. After one minute is expired you will have to re-create policy again (or create policy each time you want to add item, then it behave the way you expect).

See @JD.B answer for better *constant* policy to use.

Comment: I assumed the policy itself would not expire "absolutely" only the item. Thank you.

Comment: i had written a similar line in my property; in that, i was initiating the Timespan object and storin in my private class level variable. i dind't notice that each time i am refering to my property, it would have the old expiration date and my cache would expire the moment i added my item in

Answer (score 2):

@Sinatr's answer clears it up; the [AbsoluteExpiration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.absoluteexpiration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) policy expires the policy itself. Meaning you would need to create a new policy for each item you add; as @Sinatr said in his answer.

Meanwhile, the [SlidingExpiration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.slidingexpiration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) policy tracks the last time an item was accessed, and removes only that item if it has not be accessed within a specified time. Thus allowing you to reuse the same policy, but it does have slightly different behavior since the item's expiration timer resets every time it is accessed.

Example of SlidingExpiration:

```
MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache("C");
CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy
{
    UpdateCallback = null,
    SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)
};

cache.Add("key", "value", policy);
Console.WriteLine("1) " + cache.Get("key")); // Prints `1) value`

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5250); // Wait for "key" to expire
Console.WriteLine("2) " + cache.Get("key")); // Prints `2) `

// Just showing the the cache policy still works once an item expires.
cache.Add("key2", "value2", policy);
Console.WriteLine("3) " + cache.Get("key2")); // Prints `3) value2`

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5250); // Wait for "key2" to expire
Console.WriteLine("4) " + cache.Get("key2")); // Prints `4) `
```